# When does malloc not call mmap?

Tags: c++, c, linux, systems-programming

I'm studying operating systems at university and one of my tasks was find situation when `malloc()` doesn't cause `mmap()` system call.

I used `strace` linux utility to trace system calls, but in my situation I saw `mmap()` syscalls every time when `malloc()` was used.

Is `malloc()` always call `mmap()` or not?

Thanks

Comment: Note that you can simply get and read the source code of whatever memory allocator your system uses (or a custom one like jemalloc or tcmalloc). It is very instructive. Or you can look at [informal documentation](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals)

Comment: malloc() usually calls a user-space sub-allocator for performance reasons.  A syscall for more space can be made if the sub-allocator runs out.

Comment: I'd bet $0.02  that the `malloc()` shipped with Microsoft compilers does not call `mmap()` at all  :-)

Comment: ...or virtualAlloc(), or similar API :)

Answer (score 9):

This is defined neither by C, C++ nor the POSIX standard.

> Is malloc() always call mmap() or not?

Not necessarly. This depends on the `malloc` implementation, configuration and the size of the allocation and possibly other factors.

If using glibc:

> Tunable: glibc.malloc.mmap_threshold
>
> This tunable supersedes the MALLOC_MMAP_THRESHOLD_ environment variable and is identical in features.
>
> When this tunable is set, all chunks larger than this value in bytes are allocated outside the normal heap, using the mmap system
> call. This way it is guaranteed that the memory for these chunks can
> be returned to the system on free. Note that requests smaller than
> this threshold might still be allocated via mmap.
>
> If this tunable is not set, the default value is set to ‘131072’ bytes and the threshold is adjusted dynamically to suit the allocation
> patterns of the program. If the tunable is set, the dynamic adjustment
> is disabled and the value is set as static.

If not using glibc, then consult the documentation or source of the implementation that you use.

Answer (score 0):

> I saw mmap() syscalls every time when malloc() was used.

This statement is similar in spirit to saying "There's no way to get to work today" - it only makes sense when lots of context is known. You'd have to disclose the exact benchmark you were using, `glibc` version, distro, etc. I'm pretty sure that if you're allocating lots of small objects (e.g. 16-32 bytes), you will not be seeing `mmap()` on every call.

Syscalls are performance hogs when compared to "limited" operations on data structures, so `malloc()` would perform very poorly if it *really* always invoked `mmap()`, no matter the circumstances. Sure, if you were always calling it like `malloc(1024)`, then yes, it may end up `mmap()`-ing often.

And you'd also want to see what sort of `mmap()` arguments were passed.

So, all I see here is that your benchmark somehow is skewed against you :)